# Extract a Substring from a string in between two special characters in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string with a primary separator as `;` and secondary separator as `|`,
I need to extract the 3rd word after the separator `|` and return a single string with a separator as `;` and *trim* the rest of the string.

---

Example:

**Input:**

```
company1|23|**NJ**|0321;company2|24|**PH**|0322;company3|25|**NY**|0323;company4|26|**PA**|0323
```

**Expected Output:**

```
NJ;PH;NY;PA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please, also see my result attached;

```
string input = "company1|23|NJ|0321;company2|24|PH|0322;company3|25|NY|0323;company4|26|PA|0323";

List<string> resultLevel2 = new List<string>();

string[] resultLevel1 = input.Split(';');
foreach (var item in resultLevel1)
{
    resultLevel2.Add(item.Split('|')[2]);
}

string output = string.Join(";", resultLevel2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "company1|23|NJ|0321;company2|24|PH|0322;company3|25|NY|0323;company4|26|PA|0323";

var result = s.Split(';').Select(x=>x.Split('|')[2]).ToList();
var resultStr = string.Join(";",result);
```

Remember to include `System.Linq`

Comment: `.ToList();` is *redundant* since `string.Join` accepts `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: yup it is but I wouldn't worry ;)

Comment: Still it is not working,Giving me an error "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions".

Comment: Can i get some other approach or some other way if possible

Comment: @Learner I'm not sure where. Here is dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MR1ift